# Registry access for Asp.net web service in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, webserver, iis-7.5, registry

HI,

I am getting "Requested registry access is not allowed." exception when trying to read a registry key in Windows Server 2008 r2 64 bit edition.

I have added the IIS application pool to Administrator group but still getting same error.

So far the solution on web din't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please remove the web app from the administrators group immediate -- it should never, ever have that kind of access. As for solving the problem, first question is "what sort of key are you looking for? HKLM? HKCU?"

Comment: Change your ASP.Net app pool's .Net security setting from partial trust to full trust.  I'm not looking at the IIS console at the moment so I can't give you the exact page.

Comment: I just have the web app under admin for testing. I am looking for HKLM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has to do with granting the necessary authorization to the user account the application runs on. To read a similar situation and a detailed response for the correct solution, as documented by Microsoft, feel free to visit this post: http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed/

(from above, to prevent link rot)

1. Find key “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog”
2. Right-click and choose “Permissions”.
3. Put in the desired account

also see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842795

Answer (score 0):

<system.web>

 Added this line under <system.Web>

--> Commented This Line

</system.Web>
Now it's working for me in the Sharepoint 2019 Environment